# Converting hex value by using multiple ways results in different outputs

Tags: go

Converting an hex value with two different func result in slightly different output
For example

```
b, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("00662ad25db00e7bb38bc04831ae48b4b446d12698", 16)
fmt.Println(b.Bytes())
// output [102 42 210 93 176 14 123 179 139 192 72 49 174 72 180 180 70 209 38 152]

fmt.Println(hex.DecodeString("00662ad25db00e7bb38bc04831ae48b4b446d12698"))
// output [0 102 42 210 93 176 14 123 179 139 192 72 49 174 72 180 180 70 209 38 152]
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OchD1Zest6w).

Why is DecodeString have a leading 0 and big.Int does not?

Comment: @StevenPenny Fixed by community. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Int.SetString` method interprets the string as an encoded **number**. Leading zeros are not significant in number encodings. For example, the hexadecimal number encodings 0001 and 1 both represent the number 1.

The `hex.DecodeString` function interprets the string as hexadecimal encoded **bytes**. The leading zero byte is significant.

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse split your input, you get this:

```
00 66 2a d2 5d b0 0e 7b b3 8b c0 48 31 ae 48 b4 b4 46 d1 26 98
```

So as you can see, the MSB [1] is zero, so it is optional in the output, similar to
how this program runs successfully:

```
package main

func main() {
   println(01 == 1)
}
```

1. https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_byte